# Оптимизация медленного алгоритма

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Необходимо решить на с++ следующую задачу:  можно ли отсортировать массив Аrr (по возрастанию), выполнив переворот ровно одного подотрезка (части массива) Аrr? Если да, вывести "yes" и индексы начала подотрезка.
В противном случае вывести "no". Подробнее https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/451/B.

Мною был создан следующий алгоритм: Во вложенном цикле создаётся частично перевернутый по индексам переворота i и j(которые и перебираются во вложенном цикле) массив. При совпадении полученного таким способом массива Q и заранее отсортированного массива В выводятся индексы i и j. Ниже приведена функция переворота части массива.

Далный алгоритм работает правильно, но на одном из тестов (70+к размер массива) тестировщик выводит превышение лимита времени. Как значительно оптимизировать перебор индексов или функцию переворота части массива для уменьшения времени работы программы?
Функция переворота части массива:

```
vector<int> reverse(int l, int r, vector<int> A){
for(int i = l;i<=(l+r)/2;i++)
{
    swap(A[i],A[l-i+r]);
}
return A;
}
```

Если существенная оптимизация невозможна прошу привести более быстрый способ решения задачи.

Comment: Это возможно, если только в начале элементы расположены по убыванию, а следующие по возрастанию, притом если первый элемент второго отрезка  больше первого элемента массива. Или же если массив полностью сортирован.  Нужно только пройтись по элементам (максимум по всем) один раз

Comment: Есть же [разбор](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/13181) и даже [пример решения](https://codeforces.com/contest/451/submission/7233716).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возможна следющая оптимизация.

Для того, чтобы вывести ответ, не нужно переворачивать массив.

Нужно просто пройтись по нему, и посчитать, сколько раз происходит смена "убывания-возрастания" значений. Это делается сравнением соседних элементов массива.

Тогда если такое изменение происходит 0, 1 или 2 раза - то "да", есть монотонный кусок массива, перевернув который Вы МОЖЕТЕ получить монотонно отсортированный массив. Если таких смен возрастания-убывания больше - уже не сможете.

Но при этом надо проверить дополнительное условие: что внутри мнотонного подотрезка все значения не меньше значений в одной строне от него и не больше значений в другой стороне.

Я надеюсь, что объяснил достаточно понятно.

Если не поможет - напишите в комментариях, я напишу код

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм простой.

1. Найти начало перевернутого участка
2. Найти конец перевернутого участка
3. Перевернуть
4. Проверить стал ли массив сортированным

Код будет примерно такой (C#)

```
    private static void Solve(int[] numbers)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int end = numbers.Length - 1;

        while (start < numbers.Length - 1 && numbers[start] < numbers[start + 1])
            start++;
        while (start > 0 && numbers[start] < numbers[start - 1])
            start--;

        while (end > 0 && numbers[end] > numbers[end - 1])
            end--;
        while (end < numbers.Length - 1 && numbers[end] > numbers[end + 1])
            end++;

        if (end < start) end = start;

        swap(numbers, start, end);

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no");
                return;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("yes");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", start + 1, end + 1);
    }
```

Функция переворачивания

```
    private static void swap(int[] arr, int start, int end)
    {
        while (start < end)
        {
            int tmp = arr[start];
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = tmp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
```

Заодно [отправил решение](https://codeforces.com/contest/451/submission/91313573).